# What's an example of good style for an "if/then" statement?

Tags: writing-style, subjunctive-mood, conditionals

I'm not sure what's common for conditional statements, with and without alternative consequent clauses, in speech—even my own—but as a computer programmer, I'm niggled whenever I have to write English instructions that follow the form of a programmatic `if (condition) doThis(); else doThat();`. I was just wondering what structure seemed clearest and least ambiguous (not necessarily restricted to the following), keeping in mind that the place-holders (`condition`,`alternative`,`consequent`) might include punctuation such as one or more commas, or even a number of sub-clauses:

- If `<condition>`, `<consequent>`.
- If `<condition>`, then `<consequent>`.

With alternative:

- `<If...>`, otherwise `<alternative>`.
- `<If...>`; otherwise, `<alternative>`.
- `<If...>`. Otherwise, `<alternative>`.
- If `...` is `...`, `<consequent>`. If `...` *isn't* `...`, `<alternative>`.
- <s>`<If...>`, or else `<alternative>`.</s>

  - I've determined *"or else"*  to be poor style. *"Else"* on its own would be better but still sounds inferior to *otherwise* or negating the condition.

Comment: As you have set forth, there are many ways to express these statements. The appropriate style will depend upon the context. Can you provide more detail? How many statements of this type will there be?  Is there any nested logic involved? How technical or non-technical is the audience?

Comment: Correct use of the subjunctive tense is also important in conditional usage...

Comment: I was asking for a general case, which now seems obvious that it's very dependent on the context, although an enumeration of different cases and best style for each would be nice to have.

The original incident that prompted me to ask was when I wrote to someone something like, _"If the following report is still valid, let me know; otherwise just ignore it."_

Comment: @Mark Cidade: If you replaced "otherwise" with "or else" in your *"something like"* above, strictly speaking I would interpret that to me *"PROVIDING it's still valid, you're free to choose whether to let me know or ignore it."* The implication being that if it's NOT valid, you must come back to me for further instructions anyway.

Comment: I agree. `Or else` isn't a valid option for _good style_ in just about any case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic format is *If condition consequence*. It's largely a matter of style whether you insert a comma and/or the word *"then"* between *condition* and *consequence*.

If the statement continues with an alternative, it should be preceded by a comma or period (or sometimes a dash). The most common form is *otherwise consequence2* (optionally separated by a comma), but the word *"otherwise"* may be replaced by *In all other cases, If not, Failing that, etc.*

Variations on the second alternative involving the word *"else"* are normally either archaic, or you're writing program code.

Comment: I find "or else" to be current.

Comment: Even in **if** constructions with alternative? I think it's fine in *Do this, or else I'll do that*, but not in *If it's hot I'll go swimming, or else I'll read a book*.

Comment: _"Or else"_ is still common as a threat, often with nothing following _else_.

Comment: @Mark Cidade: Yes, but as *"Do this, or else I'll kill you"*, not *"If you do this, I'll kill you. Or else I'll marry you"*. I don't think "else" works after "if" except in programming languages.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: yes, I find that natural.

Comment: @Colin Fine: I can't tell what you mean by "that". You mean you find either or both the *second* examples in my comments above natural? If so then I guess we just have to differ - they both sound awful to me. I can't think of any simple construction using both **if** and **[or] else** that sounds okay to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: both of your examples seem natural to me (but not "else" without "or").

Comment: @Colin Fine: Weird. If "or" is present, I can only interpret, say, the second example, as meaning "If you do this I will *either kill or marry you* (but if you don't do it, I'm not saying what I'll do)". And I *am* a programmer, so it's not like I'm unfamiliar with **IF...ELSE** constructions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You're right. The _or else_ example is too contrived, and it only really makes sense as part of the conjunction—in fact, Visual Basic uses `OrElse` as a short-circuiting logical `OR`, whereas it uses `ElseIf` and `Else` for alternative branching.

Comment: I just made a desultory search of COCA for "if" collocated with "else". All I see is things like "if nothing else", "if anyone else", and similar. Perhaps there are some *"If A then B, else C"* examples in there, but they must be pretty thin on the ground.

Comment: Thinking about it, I do find _If it's hot I'll go swimming, or else I'll read a book_ natural, but the "or else" doesn't quite mean "otherwise", it means "Another possibility I've just thought of is".

Comment: @Colin: Ah - that's an interpretation I didn't think of before. I completely agree "or else" can very much imply an afterthought. But it's not the "exclusive OR" alternative applicable *if it's* **not** *hot* - it's just another possibility of what I might do if it *is* hot. I still don't see that spoken/written **English** supports IF/ELSE in the same way as, say, BASIC or COBOL.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yes, I agree with you now.

Answer (score 1):

Your first two examples are both sound, though the first sounds more natural (read: casual):

> If you heat water to 100 degrees Celsius, it boils.
>
> If you heat water to 100 degrees Celsius, then it boils.

The three *otherwise* statements are quite similar, though the first is not optimal, since it is harder to parse and understand:

> If it rains, we won't be able to attend, otherwise I see nothing against it.
>
> If it rains, we won't be able to attend; otherwise, I see nothing against it.
>
> If it rains, we won't be able to attend. Otherwise, I see nothing against it.

But the third does not fit the pattern:

> If it rains, we won't be able to attend, or else I see nothing against it.

This means *[If ... then this or that]* rather than *[If ... then this, otherwise that]*.

Comment: The first otherwise example (*If it rains, we won't be able to attend, otherwise I see nothing against it.*) is a run-on.

Comment: That's only because the purpose of the commas are ambiguous. If there was no other comma, I see nothing against it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on context. If your audience is not trained in logic, then writing a series of syllogisms, while technically more correct, might not be as helpful as something like this:

> Whenever you *(condition)*, the program will *(consequent)*.
>
> We will  *(consequent)* as long as *(condition)*.

Comment: _If_ would still be appropriate if it's expected only once (but following the consequent is common in non-technical speech or languages like PERL or Ruby).